# Touchpad not workink Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, synaptics

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook, but I can't find a way to make  my touchpad work.
The system reads the hardware, but I can't use it. In "System Options" the "active touchpad" icon is already selected.
My laptop is a Toshiba, with a Synaptics touchpad.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the troubleshooting options in this doc and see if you can get anywhere with it.  Then post if you have any issues.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Comment: I used that guide to find out if the touchpad was recognised by the notebook, but still I didn't find a solution to my problem...